# How can I edit Kerberos 5 configuration files with Perl?

Tags: perl, configuration-files, kerberos, cpan

Has anyone come across a Perl module that will parse (and write) kerberos configuration files (ie `/etc/krb5.conf`)? I have looked at quite a few parsing modules like [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General), [Config::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-Auto), etc., but none seem to be able to handle nested structures like the following:

```
pam = {
  debug = false
  ticket_lifetime = 36000
  renew_lifetime = 36000
  forwardable = true
  krb4_convert = false
}
```

It also needs to handle `INI`-style sections, for example:

```
[domain_realm]
 .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
 example.com = EXAMPLE.COM

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }
```

More details on the format can be found at [the krb5 conf documentation](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/krb5.conf.5.html)

I’m at the point of writing my own parser, but I'd rather not have to do so if someone else has written a nice, elegant module already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if it takes about 10 minutes to write a parser, it is probably not so interesting to make it a module. Here's a piece of code that probably does the job (disclaimer: I don't know anything about the config format for Kerberos, the code is based on what you posted here).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %conf;
my $section;

while (<>) {
    if (/^\s*(\S*)\s*=\s*\{\s*$/) {
        $section = $1;
        $conf{$section} = {};
    } elsif (/^\s*(\S*)\s*=\s*(\S*)\s*$/) {
        my $key = $1;
        my $value = $2;
        if ($section) {
            $conf{$section}{$key}=$value;
        }
    }
}

foreach (keys %conf) {
    $section = $_;
    foreach (keys %{$conf{$section}}) {
        print "$section:$_:$conf{$section}{$_}\n";
    }
}
```

EDIT: Parsing the ini format is not difficult either. You will just need to add a few more if's in the while loop, and make the data structure %conf slightly more complicated. Instead of a hash of hash, you will need a hash of hash of hash, where the first level key is the keyword in [...], and the second level is what I wrote here (for "pam = {").

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm heading down a similar path, but as you probably guessed, the file format is slightly more complex. I've now added some more details to the question that give a bit more detail. Thanks again for your help though.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I've ended up doing, with a bit of added logic to accept arbitrarily deep section levels.